# How to format a duration in years and months?

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I'm using node.js w/ [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) for formatting times. I want to get a patient's age formatted in months and years. Here's what I've got so far:

```
patient: {
    ...
    birthDate: moment('Dec 15, 2009'),
    getAgeString: function() {
        var age = moment.duration(moment() - this.birthDate);
        return util.format('%d years, %d months', age.years(), age.months());
    }
}
```

The `getAgeString` function gives me back `3 years, 1 months`, which is pretty close to what I want, except I'd like it to be pluralized properly. As far as I can tell, moment doesn't offer proper pluralization for durations.

`this.birthDate.fromNow(true)` is "smart" but it doesn't seem to offer any customization options as to what gets displayed.

Can I get moment.js to do what I want, or is there a better time library for node?

---

This will have to do for now:

```
getAgeString: function() {
    var age = moment.duration(moment() - this.birthDate);
    var years = age.years(), months = age.months();
    return util.format('%d year%s, %d month%s', years, years === 1 ? '' : 's', months, months === 1 ? '' : 's');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The words that you are looking to pluralize properly appear to be string literals in your own code, and not based on the formatting module.  You could do a conditional age.years() or age.months() are equal to 1.  If they are, use the strings "year" or "month", otherwise use "years" or "months".

Comment: Yes...they are string literals, but I'd prefer not to use string literals at all so that the library can handle internationalization for me as well. I just don't know how to do it.